# I got issue on browser "themes/default/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, browser

I am working on MVC. When I run my Visual Studio, I got error:

`themes/default/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

But this file is exist on my project Folder.

Thanks

Comment: did you even search online before posting you question? please show the effort conducted before posting

Comment: yes , i searched before post , Do you understand what i am  talking about ?